# Oracle: How to modify following SQL query to return 1900 instead of 2000?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date, to-char

How to modify following query to return 1900 instead of 2000?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27-OCT-00', 'DD-MON-RR') ,'YYYY') "Year"
   FROM DUAL;
```

How values are handled in 1900 and 2000.

Also suppose i save ddmmyy as 190700. How will oracle know that it is 1900 or 2000?

Comment: Another good example why it is a really bad idea to store date values in `varchar` columns

Comment: Answer: _Don't_ store your dates as text in the first place.  If you must do it, then at least use an ISO format where the year is the full 4 digits.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-44E8F6D0-7532-4BE1-9300-F9775D9DB027) "*If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then - if the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year*" there is no way you can change that rule.

Comment: I suppose you could write your own date conversion function in PL/SQL, using whatever logic you have in mind to detect the century. By the way, the `RR` format mask was a workaround for Y2K issues twenty years ago, and it just moves the problem to mid-century.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract 100 years.

```
SQL> select to_char(add_months(to_date('27-OCT-00', 'dd-mon-rr'), -12 * 100), 'yyyy') l_year from dual;

L_YE
----
1900

SQL>
```

> How will oracle know that it is 1900 or 2000?

It won't; how could it? Use 4-digits for year and you won't have problems.